# c# compilation error "missing static Main" in .net6

Tags: c#, .net, templates, .net-6.0

(beginner)

I'm trying to understand LinkedList and I have one working in .net5 but when I am trying to move it to .net6 it gives "missing static Main" error. Do I need to use the template showed in the link below or move classes to other file OR there is different work around?

At what point do I have to include old template? Is it at creating new class? Is empty template only used to create very basic code and nothing more?

I know that using template in link solves the problem but I would like to get wider understanding.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates

Comment: A windows application needs one and only one main.  A Net Class does not have a main.  So you can either change you main class to a console app or you can create a new console app which simply calls an existing class project.  A console app has a main while a class project does not have a main.

Comment: Please provide a lot more information about what you're trying to do - in particular, what project type you're using. If you can provide a [mcve], including both the C# code *and* the project file, we're much more likely to be able to help you.

Comment: @jdweng: I think you mean a class *library* project. There's no such thing as "a class project", making "A Net Class does not have a main" hard to understand too.